# Latency vs decoupling architecture advice

Tags: java, spring, design-patterns, architecture, latency

I am desgining an architecture of system.( Java EE/Spring)

The main factor of this system is **low latency**.(talking about 1 ms and less from end to end)

We have planned several components for this real time system.

My question to you experts: I know all the advantages of coupling and decoupling(fail over, separation, maintenance, extension etc..)

The problem I am facing here is:

For example let's say  I have two diffrent applications on machine A(app1) and application on Machine B(app2).

a request must go through both machines. and final answer will be sent to the client after both machines processed the request.

The integration latency between those two will surely be higher then having those apps under the same machine(networking time, etc..)

In other hand I can update and maintenance each application on it's own without being depended on the same machine. same goes for failover, clustering, load balancing

What would you advice me? what should I consider?  Latency vs decoupling and maintenance

thanks,
ray.

Comment: What do you mean by low latency? Are you talking about 100 ms, 10 ms, 1 ms, 100 us, 10 us?

Comment: Even they are on same machine, if they are two different apps, you can maintain them individually right? Which app server you are using?

Comment: Latency comes later. If your deployment is in such a way that both the machines are needed for a single request to complete, you don't have fail-over as well. In such deployment, neither of them would be capable of serving any client independently

Comment: @Peter Lawrey, Speaking about 1 ms and less!

Comment: @Nambari, right now we using Spring.

Comment: @Chris, latency cant come later. this is our main goal.. low latency! we change the current architecture because we have latency problems. so now we try to achieve the maximum considering having everything on the same jvm. but as I wrote I still need to consider more outcomes of this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> a request must go through both machines. and final answer will be sent to the client after both machines processed the request.

It could add 0.1 to 0.2 ms. This may be acceptable.

> In other hand I can update and maintenance each application on it's own without being depended on the same machine.

You are more likely to update the software than the hardware.  Hadrware can usually be updated in off peak times like on weekend.s

> same goes for failover,

The more machines you have the more points of failure you have.

> clustering

You might not need to cluster if you have it all on one machine.

> load balancing

This make more sense if you need to use multiple machines.

If you have a web application 1 ms is fairly aggressive target.  If you have a networked service such as trading system sub milli-second or even sub 100 micro-seconds is achievable depending on your requirements.

Comment: I am talking about trading system direction trying to achive latency of micro seconds. Is that achievable while having more then one machine ? what would you recommend? is the network integration between the two(or more) should be considerable ? ( I was speaking about updating software then hardware)

Comment: When I developed a trading system with a typical latency of 80 micros (from the market data hitting our network to a trade leaving it), the network latency between machines was 100 micros so it wasn't an option.  Infiniband + Java 7 may be better than the ethernet we had.

Comment: Peter, Could you tell me on which configuration you were based on getting those latency speeds? app server? hardware? thanks.

Comment: I was using Karaf+iPOJO as an light weight OSGI container, otherwise pure Java SE 6 (would use 7 now) Minimal network, locks, threads or GC.  You might find my blog interesting as I discuss many of the issue you are likely to face. http://vanillajava.blogspot.co.uk/

Comment: thanks for your links. I will follow them for sure. What is your opinion about app server like Spring(on standalone env) concerned to Latency manners? How would it affect my goal?

Comment: I have never used Spring for low latency.  The key thing is being able to write your own components which minimise GC, locks and blocking. If the Spring components you have in mind let you do that it should be fine. You will have to chose which libraries to use carefully as most are not written with latency in mind.

Comment: Do you have any design blog/articles (yours or not) links which could help me with the architecture concerned to low latency systems such as this? thanks.

Comment: First you need to identify the critical path. Next you need to make it as short and simple as possible. i.e. take out as much as you can. The most complicated bit is making it as simple as possible.  The details depend on your requirements (try to make them as simple as possible as well) Using general purpose framework make development faster, but can slow your solution so you have to know when to use them and when to replace them. To start with I would try to get something working and profile it with a commercial profiler like YourKit.

Comment: For hardware, I would consider using an overclocked CPU e.g. 5 GHz, if possible, even for your development PCs. Use Solarflare or the like if you can, again right from the development stages.

Answer (score 0):

The more machines handle the same request, the more latency - this is obvious. Moreover, eliminate all boundaries between applications - JVMs, threads, and implement them as 2 procedures called sequentially on the same thread.

More machines can decrease latency in one case: to distribute load and so to free resources (processors) on one machine, to eliminate congestion. Let different instruments (currencies, shares) be traded on different machines.

Comment: You mean I should divide the instruments to different machines? having a load balance which will decide by instrument type to which jvm to send the request?

Comment: Yes. Probably several instruments can be traded at the same machine.  if some machine become overloaded, load balancing then should move whole instrument to more free machine.